# How to add columns and rows in table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, crud

I have the following table generated in a project which makes use of DOJO toolkit:

```
<div id="table" class="crudTable">
  <div class="crudContainer">
    <div class="crudHeaderColumn crudColumn">
        <div class="crudRow crudHeader">A</div>
        <div class="crudRow crudHeader">B</div>
        <div class="crudRow crudHeader">C</div>
    </div>

    <div class="crudColumn">
        <div class="crudRow">1</div>
        <div class="crudRow">3</div>
        <div class="crudRow">3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="crudColumn">
        <div class="crudRow">4</div>
        <div class="crudRow">5</div>
        <div class="crudRow">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's basically a vertical table (with headers as the first column, and every item is another column). Suppose the database items has values for properties A,B,C and D, but the table initially renders only A,B,C properties in the view.

After table generation, I want to add a new table header (which is a new crudRow crudHeader) to add D, and consequently add a new cell for every item, to show its D value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to insert new `child`in `div` header using `appendChild()` method.

Next step is to `iterate` all `crudColumn` elements and add a new `div` for each `crudColumn`.

Here is an example.

```js
var button=document.getElementById('change');
var table=document.querySelector('#table .crudContainer');
button.onclick=function(){
  var header=document.querySelector('#table .crudHeaderColumn');
  var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.innerHTML="D";
  header.appendChild(newDiv);
  
  var rows=document.querySelectorAll('#table .crudContainer .crudColumn');
  for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++){
      var row=rows[i];
      var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
      newDiv.innerHTML="new cell";
      row.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```css
.crudColumn div{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="crudTable">
  <div class="crudContainer">
    <div class="crudHeaderColumn crudColumn">
        <div class="crudRow crudHeader">A</div>
        <div class="crudRow crudHeader">B</div>
        <div class="crudRow crudHeader">C</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="crudColumn">
        <div class="crudRow">1</div>
        <div class="crudRow">3</div>
        <div class="crudRow">3</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="crudColumn">
        <div class="crudRow">4</div>
        <div class="crudRow">5</div>
        <div class="crudRow">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

Comment: It says to me "cannot read property 0 of undefined" (var header = table.rows[0]). Could it be that you don't have one of my divs? The third line of my code, precisely.

Comment: Can you include and your `css` ?

Comment: Okay it works, thank you ;) How can I select only the crud columns and rows of this table, avoiding to use getElementsByClassName, which would apply these changes to ALL tables?

Comment: Using `document.querySelector` method.I updated my answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Just one last thing: I tried to use querySelector also here: `var rows=document.getElementsByClassName('crudColumn');` replacing it with `var rows = document.querySelector('#table .crudColumn');` but it gives me null.

Comment: You have to use this: `var rows = document.querySelector('#table .crudContainer .crudColumn');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134391/discussion-between-bransharp-and-alexandru-ionut-mihai).